# Augmentation interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to augmentation my type defined in koa middleware.first middleware to inject `userInfo` to `ctx` like this

```js
export interface UserInfo {
    isLogin: boolean,
    loginUser: {
        uid: string,
        name: string,
    }
}

declare module 'http' {
    interface IncomingMessage {
        oaUserInfo?: UserInfo
    }
}
```

and second middleware

```js
import { UserInfo } from 'first-middleware';

export interface UserInfo{
    inPasList?: {
        [K: string]: boolean
    }
}
```

but the `isPasList` is not work.Have any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it using `as` and then export the new extended type with the original name, like this:

```
import type { UserInfo as FirstUserInfo } from 'first-middleware'

export type UserInfo = FirstUserInfo & {
  inPasList?: {
    [K: string]: boolean
  }
}
```

Comment: thinks,it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

i find it should define a new variable instand of `ctx.req.userInfo`,bug it's not work in jsdoc

```
ctx.req.userInfo. // no isPasList Option

const ui: UserInfo = ctx.req.userInfo
ui. // work
```

```js
/**
 * @type {import('second-middleware').UserInfo}
 */
const ui: UserInfo = ctx.req.userInfo
ui. // no isPasList Option
```

（has changed `interface to type`）